# How to set versioning control systems through internet

Tags: version-control, dropbox

I have project on my computer and I want my colleagues to work with it.
I want them to make a changes to project and let them commit their changes.
I don't have special server for it.
What can I use (Ubuntu)?
And can I use Dropbox for this type of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use http://bitbucket.org/ you can have up to 5 private repositories.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub](https://github.com/).

Comment: @Chris: I didn't realise that was a requirement.

Comment: it's not stated as a requirement, but I think it likely that he wouldn't want to pay for it.

Comment: @Chris: +1, you're probably right, but i like Github so i wanted to give it as an alternative anyway. :)